# Recursion function; "...has stopped working"

Tags: c

I am trying to make a program that gives a specific sum until some point that I define, here it is:

```
float sum(int n,float m);

main(void) {
    float a,m=1.0;
    int n;
    scanf_s("%ld", &n);
    a = sum(n, m);
    printf("%f", a);
}

float sum(int n, float m) {
    if ((n/m) < 0.0005) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return n/m + sum(n, m + 2);
    }
}
```

(Notice that the point I defined is 0.0005) When I give a value bigger or equal to 5, program gives me this error:

> ...has stopped working

Also, when I increase the defined point to like 0.5, the number of values I can give increases too. Why do you think is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [segmentation fault using scanf with integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247345/segmentation-fault-using-scanf-with-integer)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a `%ld` (for `long int`) on an `int`? Did you see any warnings from the compiler about it?

Comment: @Alfabravo that question isn't applicable. The OP is properly using `&n` here for the `scanf_s` call.

Comment: @lurker i have been trying every possible combination to determine the problem so it doesn't really have any reason. And no i didn't get any warning.

Comment: You didn't answer my questions. You shouldn't be trying "every combination". You should only be trying combinations  that are valid. For  `int` you should use `%d` not `%ld`. When I changed your `%ld` to `%d` and fixed your `main` declaration to something  proper (which doesn't affect the test result, just clears a warning), it worked fine for me with  input of 5 on `gcc` compiler. So there's something going on here that hasn't been shared.

Comment: Can you give the full error log? I can't seem to be able to recreate your error.

Comment: @lurker the problem is that none of it works i always get the same error.

Comment: If you really did use `%d` with `int n`, then I suggest running the debugger to see where it's going awry. That's what the debugger is for. Turn on all the  warnings and heed any messages to make sure something else isn't wrong.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo Error is a simple crash "application stopped working".

Comment: What compiler do you use?

Comment: @PhotometricStereo I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: what happens if you change the function signature to: `float sum(float n, float m)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%ld` format specifier to `scanf_s` expects a `long int *` argument.  What you're passing in is a `int *`.  These types are incompatible.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), which in this case manifests as a crash.

The proper format specifier for an `int *` is `%d`:

```
scanf_s("%d", &n);
```

EDIT:

The crash you're seeing is probably a stack overflow.  The `sum` function will recursively call itself `1000 * n` times.  I see a similar error under MSVC but at a different limit.  You can get around this by going with an iterative solution:

```
float sum(int n, float m){
  float result = 0;
  while ((n/m) >= 0.0005){
    result += n/m;
    m+=2;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why it would still work for the OP when `n` values lesser than 5? Is it just because it's undefined behavior? Since OP used `scanf_s()` he has to be using Microsoft which should have still given him a compile time error for having `%ld`.

Comment: @PhotometricStereo Undefined behavior.  That means it could crash, it could give strange results, or it could appear to work properly.

Comment: Okay here's the thing, i changed the specifier to correct one. But i still have a crash.It works correctly until i give input "5". When i give "5" program stops for a second without giving any results and then crashes with the same error.

Comment: @GöktuğSaray See my edit.  You're blowing up the stack.