# How to enter if statement inside a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying calculate the average of 5 numbers, all of them being lower than 10.
Any help would be much appreciated since I'm still very much in the early stages of learning.

```
int num1, num2;
  int sum, i;
  float average;

  printf ("Enter five numbers to calculate the average:");

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      scanf ("%d", num1);

      if (num1 > 10){
      printf ("You can't enter this number\n");
      printf ("Enter five numbers to calculate the average:");
      scanf ("%d", num1);
    }
    else{
        num1=num2;
    }
    sum += num2;
  }

  average = sum / 5;
  printf ("Average is: %f", average);
```

Comment: `scanf ("%d", num1);` => `scanf ("%d", &num1);`

Comment: Your issue is what to do if user input greater than 10 number?

Comment: What is the problem you have with the code you show? What is your question?  Write your question *in* the actual question body, and keep the title a short summary of your problem. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And also please learn how to create a [Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: read about scanf: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247345/segmentation-fault-using-scanf-with-integer, then read about [mcve] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: As new in c start to check the return value of `scanf`. Another problem with your code is that you assign at `num1` the `num2` which is uninitialized. So you lost all your input.

Comment: another issue with your code is that `average = sum / 5;` will give you the truncated division instead of a floating-point division, because `sum` is an `int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first job is to write `scanf("%d", &num1);`, note the *pointer*. Eventually you should check the return value of `scanf` too - it should be 1 if a number was read.

One way (not to everyone's taste) would be to rewrite the `if` body as

```
if (num1 > 10){
    printf ("You can't enter this number\n");
    printf ("Enter five numbers to calculate the average:");
    --i;
} ...
```

which reverses out the incrementation of `i`.

Another way (which I would prefer) would be to only increase `i` in the `else` branch, and drop the `i++` from the third `for` loop expression.

Your assignment `num1 = num2;` is buggy too, nothing that you can't solve with a debugger, and you'll also realise you'll need `average = sum / 5.0f;` to avoid a truncation.

Comment: @Ctx: Well `&num1` is a pointer: 6 of one and 1/2 dozen of another methinks.

Comment: @Ctx: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/six_of_one,_half_a_dozen_of_the_other